# Placing a table at the bottom right of the screen

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to provide menu with CSS and javascript. I would like to place a table at the bottom right of the screen and have it expand up. Currently, the table always expands down or tries to cram itself into the footer element containing the table. How do you force a table to expand up? The overflow style doesn't seem to provide the desired functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check the JS code (and/or put it in jsbin so we could have a look)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your CSS.

```
table.bottomRight {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Comment: This is what I originally tried, and it does work when the element is placed directly in the document. (Not nested inside a table, for example). We have a table that is used to identify 'zones' on the page, and I'm trying to add the menu item inside a row at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
table {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 500px;
}

table th {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

table th, table td {
  padding: 10px;
}

table tbody {
  display: none;
}
```

And javascript for demonstration purposes:

```
$('#test-button').bind('click', function() {
  var tableBody = $('table tbody');
  tableBody.toggle();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8SvCm/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback. The solution I found is documented here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1740-Building-A-Fixed-Position-Bottom-Menu-Bar-ala-FaceBook-.htm

It uses jQuery and a combination of nested divs and CSS to achieve the menu. Very cool!

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer. Having said that, your question was not specific enough for anyone **else** to have been able to answer it. In future, please be more specific. For more tips, [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).